# Fancyhdr only shows [L]

Tags: fancyhdr

I am writing a syllabus, and I would like to have the school logo on the left side of the header. I would like to have the course in the center of the header. However, no matter where I put the course text, I have tried [C] and [R], it does not display. I have attached a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,url}
\geometry{body={7.0in,9.5in}, top=1in, centering} % Adjust top margin here
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Add the fancyhdr package
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[backend=biber,texencoding=utf8,bibencoding=utf8,language=auto]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Set the header height
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt} % Adjust as needed

% Define the firstpage style
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=1.2in]{example-image}} 
  \fancyhead[R]{\textbf{OT630 Biblical Aramaic}\\Spring 2024\\Tyndale Theological Seminary\\ Department of Biblical and Exegetical Studies\\}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{custom}{
  \fancyhf{} % Clear header and footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header rule line
  \fancyhead[C]{OT630 Biblical Aramaic} % Centered header
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{firstpage}
On the subsequent pages it should have the custom header. This shows up fine.
\pagestyle{custom}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is on the other pages. That works fine. I can remove it from the MWE.

Comment: Your example produced no output at all, I modified it slightly but now it is a 1 page document with empty head as you have `\thispagestyle{empty}` on the first page so the `firstpage` style is only used on later pages

Comment: on the second page you get an [image on left  and the address on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMBQD.png)

Comment: I removed `\thispagestyle{empty}`. Now only the `custom` shows up and not the `firstpage` that I also defined. I want the `firstpage` to appear on the first page and `custom` to appear on the subsequent pages.

Comment: @ceramicquasar88 Please show the [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/277964) that really produces what you are describing, because currently you example only shows a what David describes in his comments. Currently there isn't even a page style `custom` defined. However, maybe you want `\pagestyle{custom}\thispagestyle{firstpage}`.

Comment: I have added `\pagestyle{custom}` back to the MWE.

Comment: The problems are different each time you change the example, so it's hard to answer. Currently the issue is that you select custom page style while still on the first page so the firstpage style is never used.  set it later or use \thispagestyle for the first page

Comment: Note that `\pagestyle` does not add a new page, but it only sets the style for the *current* page. So, if you set `\pagestyle` multiple times on the same page, the last setting will have effect. As has been noted above, what you probably want is `\pagestyle{custom}\thispagestyle{firstpage}` to set the style of the first page to `firstpage` and the style of all other pages to `custom`. For testing purposes, you can add `\newpage` to add a new page (or just fill your document with text generated by, for example, the `lipsum` package).

Comment: Thanks @JasperHabicht. That solved the problem. That is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: Thank you all for your help.